# When editing a membership Civi sends receipt and confirmation even with box unchecked

Tags: civimember, receipts

Using WP4.3.1 and CIviCRM 4.6.9
I also had this happen on the current CiviCRM.org demo site for WP.

When editing a membership Civi sends receipt and confirmation even when the box for "Send Confirmation and Receipt?" is Unchecked.

Is this a bug or am I missing something?
Of course we do NOT want to send receipts for most edits we make!

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked that the mails are actually being sent out?

In civiCRM 4.6.4 I have found that I receive the following pop-up when editing a membership record with an attached contribution record (this does not seem to occur when there is no contribution recorded with the membership), but if the "Send Confirmation and Receipt" box is unchecked, no mails are actually sent out even though I got the message below.

[image: civiMember confirmation and receipt notice]